# Program will not exit after calling exit()

Tags: c++

I have the following code. Can someone explain to me why the program will not exit when "exit" is typed. The program works and if you type exit when it begins it works. Program will not exit after you enter a words for example typing a then b and then c you would have to type exit 4 times to exit the program

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wait.h>

using namespace std;

//*********************************************************
//
// Extern Declarations
//
//*********************************************************
using namespace std;
extern "C" {
    extern char **gettoks();
}

//*********************************************************
//
// Main Function
//
//*********************************************************
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // local variables
    int ii;
    char **toks;
    int retval;

    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    char folder[80];
    retval = 0;

    cout << "Welcome to Island Shell" << endl;
    while (true)
    {
        printf("Island Shell$ ");
        toks = gettoks();
        if (toks[0] != NULL)
        {
            if( !strcmp( toks[0], "exit" ))
            {
                exit(0);
            }
            pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0)
            {
                strcpy(folder,"/bin/");
                strcat(folder,toks[0]);
                execv(folder,toks);
            }
            else
            {
                wait(&status);
            }
        }
    }
    return (retval);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is reaching that code?  Try adding a trace line and see if it is reaching it at all.

Comment: @solarflare yes I reach the code. What happens for example if I type 1 and then 2 and then 3, I'll have to type exit 4 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show `char **gettoks()`, so it is hard to know for sure, but here is my guess, assuming that the function returns your keyboard input.

When you type 1, you get `tok[0]==1`, after which `fork()` creates the 2nd copy of the same process, and waits while it ends. The intention is to replace this new process with another program by calling `execv`, but `execv` does not find a program named `1` and fails, so you end up with 2 copies of the same process.

After you repeat it by entering 2 and then 3, you end up with 4 copies of your process waiting for each other. It takes 4 `exit` commands to exit all 4 processes.

Comment: I'm reading over system calls in my OS book but can't seem to find the answer to it. I now know what the issue is, thank you. Can't seem to find if there is a way to terminate the process if it doesn't find the program named `1` for example.

Comment: Just add `exit(1)` call after `execv()`. The program will not reach it if `execv()` succeded.